# isolated scope two way binding is not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I am working with isolated scope. The two way binding using isolated scope is not working. Please check my code. If i remove age : '=' then my code is working fine.

```
**HTML**

<div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <my-dir name="{{namee}}" age="{{age}}"></my-dir>
</div>

**JS**

var app = angular.module("home")
app.controller("homeCtrl",["$scope",function($scope){
   $scope.namee = "John";
   $scope.age= 30;
}]);

app.directive("myDir",function(){
    return{
        restrict :'E',
        scope: {
            name : '@',
            age :  '=',
        },
        template: ['Directive name is: {{name}}',
                   '<p>{{age}}</p>' 
                 ]
        }
})


**Output**

John 30 
Directive name is: {{name}} {{age}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
<div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
  <my-dir name="name" age="age"></my-dir>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the `{{}}` use just `age="age"`